# Navigate to specific page defined on model when Item is Tapped

Tags: events, xamarin.forms, model, navigation

I'm trying to make a custom home page where pages are listed on an Horizontal scroll view as "Services" so each one of them should navigate to a different Page.

I have a view like this:

```
           <controls:HorizontalScrollView HeightRequest="160" 
                                   Orientation="Horizontal"  
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding OwnerServicesList}"
                                   x:Name="OwnerServicesSlider"
                                   ItemSelected="OwnerServicesSlider_ItemSelected">

                <controls:HorizontalScrollView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Margin="10,0,5,0" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100">
                                <Image HorizontalOptions="Start"  Source="{Binding ImgUrl}" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" />
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource BoldLabel}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Im using a custom made controller for a Horizontal Scroll view that works like a listview, every item on tap raises a **ItemTappedEventArgs event.**

Inside my model i´ve declared a `public Page Page { get; set; }` for each object in the scroll view.

What im trying to do is recover the tapped element and recover the Page stored in it so that I can Navigate to that specific page.

So far I have something like this:

```
private void OwnerServicesSlider_ItemSelected(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var service = OwnerServicesSlider.SelectedItem as Services;   
            Navigation.PushAsync(service.Page);
        }
```

It shows no errors but when I run it I get a

> InvalidOperationException: 'Page must not already have a parent.

Any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: you're trying to push an instance of Page that already exists in the current navigation structure.  This is not allowed.

Comment: check to see if the page you want to start is open.

Comment: try to set service.Page.Parent = null before pushAsync.

Comment: Thank you @LeoZhu-MSFT your awnser worked like a charm. Im new to stackOverflow how can I mark your commnet as an awnser?

Comment: @Jd996 i have post it as an answer,you could check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Jason said,maybe the page you would push which is exist in thecurren navigation structure,there is a workaround ,before you push the page :

```
 private void OwnerServicesSlider_ItemSelected(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var service = OwnerServicesSlider.SelectedItem as Services;
        service.Page.Parent = null;             
        Navigation.PushAsync(service.Page);
    }
```